# PowerPoint VBScript set textbox text delay

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am using VBScript to do some programming in a powerpoint presentation.

When my slide is currently on slide 1, I call some code to populate some text boxes on slide 2 and 3, then I call to transition to slide 2.

But when the transition begins to slide 2, the text is not yet set on slide 2, even though that code executed before the code to transition slides. So you can see the text populating after you transition to slide 2.

Is there a way to rectify this?

```
        ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("slide2_text").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "text value 1"
        ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("slide_3_title").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "text value 2"
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide 2
```

Comment: You're using VBA, not VBScript, so you might want to change the tags to reflect that. As to the problem you're facing, try adding one or more calls to DoEvents() after changing the text but before moving to slide 2.  It sometimes takes as many as five calls to DoEvents to sort things out, perhaps more.

Comment: Even if you use only the UI, it can happen that you change something on the slide but some parts of the window does not get updated. In this case I minimize the window, restore it, and it gets updated. Using VBA you may try Application.Visible = False: Application.Visible = True. (Or UpdateWindow, if you are familiar with WinAPI, and how to use it from VBA.)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg: I don't think that DoEvents would help in this case. That is rather for situations where a deadlock or starvation would occur between your background calculation and the UI.

Comment: Why not try it?  If it works, you have a solution. If not, you've lost a few minutes at most.